# Creating local branches with Repo

Tags: git, repo

We've started using Repo (described here: https://source.android.com/source/developing.html) to manage our set of git repositories. After doing init and sync, all the repositories have detached HEADs.

When the manifest version of a repository is a branch, I would like to automatically create a local branch tracking the remote one, for all git repositories in the manifest. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes use the repo forall command. Look at repo help forall for more information.

for more info see https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#forall

If you want to specify the manifest revisions exactly (these will generally be the branch names specified in the manifest) but manifests can contain SHAs as well.

```
repo forall -c 'git branch new_branch $REPO_RREV'
```

Comment: But if the branches do not have the same name in all the repositories, that won't work?

Comment: You can use REPO_LREV instead of REPO_RREV but both should work since they are special variable that is evaluated on each repository separately.  I have written scripts that use both.  You may want to use $REPO_REMOTE/$REPO_RREV to fully qualify the remote branch name.  From the forall help:

REPO_LREV is the name of the revision from the manifest, translated to a local tracking branch. If you need to pass the manifest revision to a
locally executed git command, use REPO_LREV.

REPO_RREV is the name of the revision from the manifest, exactly as
written in the manifest.

Comment: Is manually running `repo forall` the only option? There's no way to create a local tracking branch automatically by default? What is the benefit to creating detached HEADs?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar when applying a number of security patches. I managed to checkout the relevant branch in each repo with a single command

```
repo forall -c 'echo  $REPO_RREV | sed -e "s%refs/heads/%%" | xargs git checkout
```